Does severity of a punishment increase with potential reward?
I will defer to UK (where I live) and US (which more popularly understood) law.
I was thinking about paparazzi and Tabloids, and assumed charges for libel or privacy breaches often are worth risking for the amount of money made, however is that really the case? Not just for this example, but if you commit a crime knowing that it will be worth a lot if you get away with it, are there any cases in which you would be punished more severely than if you commit the same crime standing to gain less?
Philosophically it seems that it would make sense as a deterrent by keeping risk-reward constant.


Does severity of a punishment increase with potential reward?

Sometimes yes, and sometimes no. There is no uniform answer and the law is not consistent on that point. Legislators consider this issue, but it isn't the only issue that they consider and often legislators operate more on gut feelings than cold rational analysis of costs and benefits.
Some criminal statutes (especially criminal theft) adjust punishments expressly by potential reward, and potential reward is a factor that may be considered when judges have discretion in sentencing. If the crime causes direct economic harm, a restitution award to the victim is also often part of the sentence.
Other crimes often don't have punishments related to amount of the potential reward, and particularly for minor crimes, there is often, in practice, a routine sentence that is imposed in all but the most exceptional cases (in the old days when a "court blotter" in the local newspaper reported all sentences imposed in the local court, this was obvious).
Also, many crimes can be pursued as intentional torts, in which case the actual gain received or the actual harm done is critical in the amount of a judgment awarded in a civil lawsuit brought by the victim against the perpetrator arising out of the incident.
Some crimes, like traffic offenses and prostitution related charges, often have low penalties that can be thought of as just the cost of getting something you want. Likewise, fines for violating health, safety, and environmental laws and regulations are often much less than the financial benefit to the perpetrators associated with breaking those laws and regulations.
On the other hand, the harms to someone who is convicted of having a criminal record, and the collateral effects of felony convictions are often far in excess of the potential rewards, making a first criminal conviction particularly costly.

Re your 2nd-to-last paragraph, I've heard that many companies include potential fines in their budgeting.

@Barmar which is why many jurisdictions also include jail time for executives who enable the breach of those laws.

In some very rare cases, fines can be a proportion of a company's turnover or profit.

@DaleM Like all the bank CEOs who went to jail after the financial meltdown. Oh wait....
